# How to detect CPU id in gcc

Tags: c, windows-8, mingw, cpu, cpuid

I want to write a c program that can detect CPU id for activation process. 
Some advise me to use UUID but I like to try CPU id instead. After searching I found [some good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466377/how-to-detect-what-cpu-is-being-used-during-runtime). But I am using Windows 8 64bit and Mingw. So I am afraid I cant use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, two pieces of information, since you wanted to be guided and not shown code :)

1. Use the CPUID x86 instruction http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_45.html
2. ... with gnu inline assembler syntax for C programs
   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

That's it. Create a small inline C function that has an asm {} block in it and the single instruction inthere would be CPUID.Be aware of how to return values from these assembly blocks, gcc has a special syntax for it.

With this info, I reckon you can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much :). It help me a lot. Let me test it bro.

Comment: @BluePhoenix please mark this as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure bro I will for sure, but I don't know how to :P wait pls. And I cant vote either since I don't have enough reputation here :(

Comment: Andre Finally I found it :)