# How to differentiate between Intel CPU generations in C++ at runtime?

Tags: c++, x86, intel, simd, intrinsics

[SIMD has had an initialisation cost on Intel CPUs in the past.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74788707/9671117) Because of this, I am looking for a way to distinguish at runtime in C++ which generation of Intel CPU is running my program.

Is there a simple way to discriminate all Intel CPUs older than [Ice Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Lake_(microprocessor))?

NB: [detecting whether the CPU running is an Intel CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466389/9671117) is fairly simple but sadly isn't enough for this use case.

Comment: Both the `/proc/cpuinfo` file (in supporting environments) and the `cpuid` instruction can give a *lot* more information. Look more into those.

Comment: I imagine you're hoping for an easy way to extract the "generation number" from the family/model numbers but that's not so simple and cannot be future-proof

Comment: "Generation" is very much a marketing thing at Intel. "Ice Lake" is both the 10th generation and the 3rd generation - because Intel's server marketing recently reset the generation count, but their mobile group didn't. And the Jasper Lake Celeron is newer than Ice Lake, but sufficiently unrelated to Ice Lake that the test makes little sense.

Comment: @MSalters That is indeed what got me confused. [cpuid info doesn't seem too reliable for this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=0:_Highest_Function_Parameter_and_Manufacturer_ID) I was hoping there was maybe another new feature adding a flag to Ice Lake CPUs & newer that could be used.

Comment: This is an XY question of course - it starts out by assuming that "generation" is meaningful, but the real motivation seems to be initialization cost, and the assumption is that "generation" is inversely related. Perhaps it's even an XYZ question, because those initialization costs are probably not the real issue either.

Comment: A good practical approximation is to test for a CPU feature that is only supported since Ice Lake. For example, AVX512_VBMI2 or GFNI. The latter will also work on CPUs that don't support AVX-512, like Alder Lake and its descendants.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I checked a few CPUs and for example the [i7-14700KF](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/236789/intel-core-i7-processor-14700kf-33m-cache-up-to-5-60-ghz/specifications.html) doesn't have AVX-512 support (and therefore no AVX512_VBMI2) despite being from Q4 2023. Relying on an AVX512 related flag doesn't seem reliable to identify any post-IceLake CPU. For GFNI, I am unable to see it on the product page so I'm not really sure how to check if it really is on these CPUs.

Comment: @Norgannon You can see the list of the 14th gen CPU features on the screenshot [here](https://www.phoronix.com/review/intel-14600k-14900k-linux). It does support GFNI.

Comment: Why is 14 microseconds such an issue for you?

Comment: "Warm up" effects (throttling throughput of "heavy" instructions if the current voltage isn't high enough for the frequency, or the frequency is too high) mostly matters for 512-bit uops.  If a CPU doesn't support AVX-512 at all, you're stuck using AVX2+FMA regardless.  (It's generally not worth limiting yourself to 128-bit uops; even Skylake-server didn't have to reduce clock speed much for those, and glibc functions like `strchr` and `memcmp` use AVX2 already.  Although only "light" integer instructions, not multiplies or FP so on most CPUs that's the same turbo "license" as 128-bit heavy.)

Comment: See [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56852812) for a more detailed answer about CPU frequency effects of SIMD.

Comment: @AndreySemashev True, but I just can't find a source stating that GFNI is here to stay on all consumer CPUs. Intel documentation only talks about it as being introduced in "3rd Gen Intel® Xeon® Scalable processor" and doesn't even mention the more classical desktop CPUs. Since they don't bother writing about that feature on their own product pages I don't know if it's really 100% reliable.

Comment: @PaulSanders I have seen use cases where those 14ms were an issue. If you are able to bundle your AVX calculations neatly and just suffer that 14ms once before a bunch of calculations, then it's not that bad. But for some other use case where AVX may be used only briefly, the "warm up" penalty matters. It's probably going to be forgotten soon as newer Intel CPUs (and AMD) don't have that to consider any more. But I'd rather be safe for now, especially given that I am still working on a Skylake CPU with such penalty.

Comment: @PeterCordes Very interesting link to read, thank you! I can confirm that my experience confirms what the guidelines in the answer state (no issue with 128-bit instructions whatsoever but 256-bit instructions may be more tricky).

Comment: @Norgannon Of course there's no guarantee that the feature won't be removed. Just as there is no guarantee that no future CPU generation will reintroduce a warmup delay for AVX instructions or whatever. Either way you will have to make some assumptions and test newer CPU generations if the workaround you've implemented is still working and required. My point is simply that checking for a CPU feature works rather well in practice; much better than checking for the CPU family and model, for example.

Comment: @Norgannon You didn't answer the question :)

Comment: @AndreySemashev Alright, I guess that's fair! Thank you very much!

Comment: @PaulSanders If a newer version of the program is shipped with about 10% faster calculations (*on newer CPUs) advertised, some customers will try it. Some with old CPUs might see (slightly) worse performance than the previous unoptimized version. It's easier if we can make sure this situation doesn't happen by disabling the modifications on those older CPUs. That's the main reason why 14µs matter: some customers will complain, especially if they feel we lied about the improvements. Also not just 14µs in reality but even worse (cf [Peter Cordes link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56852812)).

Comment: @Norgannon Three words: benchmark, benchmark, benchmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually checking for cpu attributes at runtime, you can let the compiler figure it out for your at load time with compiler target attributes (or function multi-versioning as GCC calls it).

Unfortunately it's not a standard feature even in between the "three big" compilers but both clang and gcc at least provide similar implementations.

There is [a tutorial here](https://lucisqr.substack.com/p/clanggcc-target-attributes) that discusses workarounds for a couple of edge cases but in general this should be fairly transparent.

You can look at [this code on Github](https://github.com/HFTrader/AssemblyTales/tree/main/Target) but basically there are two ways to do it.

First with `target` you can manually implement versions for each architecture

```cpp
namespace detail {
inline Vector multiply(const Matrix& m, const Vector& v) {
    Vector r;
    r[0] = v[0] * m[0] + v[1] * m[2];
    r[1] = v[0] * m[1] + v[1] * m[3];
    return r;
}
}  // namespace detail

__attribute__((target("default"))) Vector multiply(const Matrix& m, const Vector& v) {
    printf("default\n");
    return detail::multiply(m, v);
}

__attribute__((target("arch=core2"))) Vector multiply(const Matrix& m, const Vector& v) {
    printf("core2\n");
    return detail::multiply(m, v);
}

__attribute__((target("arch=sandybridge"))) Vector multiply(const Matrix& m, const Vector& v) {
    printf("sandybridge\n");
    return detail::multiply(m, v);
}
```

Second with `target_clones` is more convenient if all the implementations are similar in code as you select all possible architectures to version it.

```cpp
__attribute__((target_clones("default", "arch=core2", "arch=sandybridge", "arch=haswell", "arch=cascadelake",
                             "arch=znver1", "arch=znver2"))) Vector
multiply(const Matrix& m, const Vector& v) {
    Vector r;
    r[0] = v[0] * m[0] + v[1] * m[2];
    r[1] = v[0] * m[1] + v[1] * m[3];
    return r;
})
```

Once you run, the linked code will automagically select the right implementation for your target machine.

Read more: [Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-target_005fclones-function-attribute)

Comment: That's an interesting alternative to know exists! I definitely have to read a bit more about it. Thank you! Would you know if MSVC in particular also has an implementation of this feature? I can't find it so assume it doesn't but I might no be using the right key words.

Comment: @Norgannon As far as I know, it doesn’t. (1) No support for multi-versioning (2) VC++ compiler doesn’t distinguish between these generations at compile time either. It only has switches to enable/disable AVX1/AVX2/AVX512, but it doesn’t have switches to specifically optimize for Skylake/Zen3/etc.

Comment: If you really need that in Visual Studio, I believe a while ago Microsoft shipped a fork of clang as an optional feature of the IDE. You could try switching your compiler from MSVC to that one, but I don’t have hands-on experience with that thing.

Comment: @Soonts Interesting! Switching completely from MSVC to Clang would most likely be more trouble than it is worth here. I'll probably just rely on GFNI being implemented to identify Ice Lake+ Intel CPUs on MSVC. I'm also working on GCC/Clang compatibility, so... using this more reliable solution is tempting but mixing the two solutions might be a poor decision. I'll think about it. Maybe in the long run that will the solution, unless the issue has become too old and those older CPUs are nowhere to be seen at that point.